# How to use ark on a hosted chef node

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook

i added the ark cookbook in the run list of my hosted chef node.
Now i want to use ark in another cookbook, that comes right after the ark cookbook.

I included the ark recipe in the recipe of the cookbook that comes right after the ark cookbook. The code looks like this:

```
include_recipe "ark"
```

dowloading olio

```
subversion "checkout-olio" do
  repository "https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/olio/"
  revision "HEAD"
  destination "/usr/local"
  action :checkout
end
```

install faban

```
ark "install-faban" do
  url "http://java.net/projects/faban/downloads/download/faban-kit/faban-kit-022311.tar.gz"
  version "1.0"
  path "/usr/local"
  append_env_path true
end
```

When i upload this file and run the client the following error occurs:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `url' for Chef::Resource::Ark
```

Can somebody please tell me where the problem is?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this cookbook, but it looks like the attribute for ark is release_url not url:

```
 release_url: url for tarball, .tar.gz, .bin (oracle-specific), .war, and .zip currently supported. Also supports special syntax :name:version:apache_mirror: that will auto-magically construct download url from the apache mirrors site
```